# Storybook - how to provide a function as an arg?

Tags: storybook

With this story:

```
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/react';

import { ButtonProps } from './Button.types';
import Button from './Button';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: Button,
} as Meta;

export const Default: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;
```

I'm getting the following:
[image]

How can i provide a value for the `handleClick` function, similar to the other values?